# HTML5 required messsege

Tags: jquery, html, required

I am trying to make input field required box custom message. But I have problem, because I have like 5 input fields. I am changing with jQuery. If I write else if like 5 times for different input name I cant get my message but if I write if for every input field I have press submit like twice to get message in second input field.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/L35eortb/)

Comment: What are you using jQuery for? Your fiddle has no jQuery code at all.

Comment: The second input is type email, you must write someone like this: name@server. If you don't write the `@` char this field is invalid

Comment: How no jquery ? http://snag.gy/3vdW0.jpg I just took print screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to validate your form.
First you need validate form before send. 
You can do it with add **onsubmit** attribute into **form** html tag. 
Then validate form in js and if validation have an error, you stop form sending with **return false;** in your script.

So follow this working example and learn more.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

IN JQUERY
you can use this http://happyjs.com/